# Remove an Object from a collection with hibernate ManyToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate

Would anyone help with this?

I am currently facing an issue when removing a teacher from a course in hibernate ManyToMany association. I can add a teacher to a course but cannot remove it.I have a view that display a model with the course and its associated teachers. When I persist a new teacher and add him to a course, everything works fine. But when I remove the teacher, the view still displays the course with the  teacher.

```
// inside the teacher class
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "teachers")
private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();

// inside the course class
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="COURSE_TEACHERS",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="COURSE_ID")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ID")})
private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();

//here is how I am trying to remove the teacher from the course
@Override
public void removeTeacherFromCourse(Course course, Teacher teacher) {
    course.getTeachers().remove(teacher);
    updateCourse(course);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've got is you're cascading changes to teachers, but not cascading changes to courses. If you come at this problem from the other angle it should work how you expect it too.

Instead of removing the teacher from the course, you need to remove the course from the teacher and let Hibernate cascade the change that way.

```
@Override
public void removeTeacherFromCourse(Course course, Teacher teacher) {
    teacher.getCourses().remove(course);
    updateTeacher(teacher);
}
```

This is because of where you've placed your annotations. Because you've set your `JoinTable` declaration on teachers, that's the side of the object that 'owns' the relationship. You need to do all your manipulation on that side so that changes are cascades across to your other objects.

Comment: the course class in the owner of the relation because that's where I have the joint table annotion.